# griddata interpolation for 4D (x,y,t -> u_pred) instead of 3D (x,t->y_pred) in python

Tags: python, plot, interpolation

In this python code:

```
X_star = np.hstack((xx.flatten()[:,None], tt.flatten()[:,None]))
Y_pred = griddata(X_star, y_pred.flatten(), (xx, tt), method='cubic')
```

Y_pred is interpolated according to y_pred, but I want to do the same for a larger dimension, so I modified it to be:

```
X_star = np.hstack((xx.flatten()[:,None], yy.flatten()[:,None], tt.flatten()[:,None]))
U_pred = griddata(X_star, u_pred.flatten(), (xx, yy, tt), method='cubic')
```

However, it throws an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown interpolation method 'cubic' for 3 dimensional data
```

How to implement the equivalent line for 4D?